# Is it possible to edit all texts without affecting other curves using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I have run into an issue where I need to edit all text curves to change their content, but I also need to be able to use other curves that are not text within the scene.

If I try and use the standard `for x in y` method and cycle through all curves I get the error I expected.

```
import bpy

curves = bpy.data.curves

for c in curves:
  print(c.data.body)
  c.data.body = 'this has worked'
```

`'Curve' object has no attribute 'data'`

This is caused by non-text curve objects in the scene, which of course have no text attributes. What are my options to work around this limitation of having text objects bundled in with all curve objects?

Adding text object definitions manually is not an option as this needs to be extremely flexible.

Comment: The error above isn't caused by the curve not being a `TextCurve`. The curve is the data property of a curve object.  There is no data attribute of a curve. ie should be `print(c.body)`  Then you will need to check for `TextCurve`.

Comment: @batFINGER How you usually address a single text curve's text content is with `bpy.data.curves['CurveName'].data.body` which is why it was written the way it is. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Change to `bpy.data.objects['TextName"].data.body` and I'd agree.  Only *objects* have the data prop that can be a curve, in `bpy.data.curves`, a mesh in `bpy.data.meshes` etc.

Comment: @batFINGER I think I see where my confusion first arose, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited, thanks.

```
import bpy

curves = bpy.data.curves

for c in curves:
    if isinstance (c, bpy.types.TextCurve):
        print(c.body)
        c.body = 'this works in better style'
```

Comment: Good idea, I'll wait to see if there is a better method but this looks like it would work well if not. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Blender's internals, but for Python it's typically better to use `isinstance(obj, class_or_classes)` instead of `type(obj) is cls` so that subclasses are supported as well.

Comment: Could use `hasattr(c, "font")` or `hasattr(c, "body")`